# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una consulta de horas con datos datetime?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito realizar una consulta mayor a esta hora '2018-11-01 00:36:14.000'

Estoy intentando con esto:

```
declare @fch_min datetime 

-- con esta consulta tengo esto :00:36:14 

set @fch_min=(select min(convert(varchar,received,108)) from events
where address like '%S CONTRANS I%' and plate like '%D7Z716%'
and CONVERT(varchar,received,103)='01/11/2018')
```

ahora quiero sacar una hora mayor a la fecha consultada

```
select max(convert(varchar,received,108)) from events where convert(varchar,received,108)>@fch_min
and plate like'%D7Z716%' and address like '%S CONTRANS I%'
```

Necesito sacar una de estas fechas que es mayor a 00:36.

```
07:38:15
07:38:16
07:38:18
07:38:20
07:38:21
07:38:23
07:38:24
07:38:36
07:39:37
07:40:47
07:43:22
07:43:25
07:43:26
07:50:36
07:50:56
08:56:09
08:56:28
08:57:26
08:57:58
11:26:51
11:26:51
11:27:50
11:28:51
11:29:23
11:30:08
11:30:15
11:30:22
12:38:59
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases por la sección de [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que mejores tu pregunta, y cuentanos que haz intentado en base a lo que solicitas, podrias ingresar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hola compañero voy a editar ahora la pregunta vale

Comment: @KevinQuevedo también mira aquí [las demás funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Qué dificultad tienes para hacer algo como: `select x from y where fecha >= '20181101 00:36:00'?

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, estás usando las horas, minutos y segundos de la fecha proporcionada.

Necesitas aplicar un formato a la variable @fch_min de esta manera:

```
convert(datetime, @fch_min, 108)
```

Por lo que, al modificar la consulta, quedaría así:

```
select max(convert(varchar,received,108))
from events where convert(varchar,received,108) > convert(datetime, @fch_min, 108) 
and plate like'%D7Z716%' and address like '%S CONTRANS I%'
```

Puedes mirar [aquí](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/) algunos de los formatos de fecha.

Comment: acabo de modificar mi consulta y me sale este resultado : 23:59:19